# I get an error message in csound and I don't know why

Tags: syntax-error, csound

I don't know what is wrong with my code, and I don't know what thie error message I got means. I just started using Csound with Cabbage, and coding in general.

I'm trying to ude 1 slider to set the values of multiple variables. I used the slider to set a value for 1 variable, and used some if-then-else statements to set values for other variables.

> if kV0 == 1 then kV = 1, kVA = 0, kVB = 0, kV1 = kV2 = kV3 = kV4 = 0

I expect kV to be set to 1 and all other variables to be set to 0 when kV0 is equal to 1. I keep getting this message:

> error: syntax error, unexpected T_IDENT, expecting NEWLINE  (token "kV")
>
> line 69:
>
> if kV0 == 1 then kV
>
> Parsing failed due to invalid input!

Answer (score 0):

Code like this isn't valid Csound code and you will need to separate the statements onto separate lines, like so:

```
if kV0 == 1 then 
  kV = 1
  kVA = 0
  kVB = 0
  kV1 = 0
  kV2 = 0
  kV3 = 0
  kV4 = 0
endif
```